# Tags with hyphens in them can wrap incorrectly on mobile version

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, mobile

When a tag includes one or more hyphens (as in the `mac-os-x` tag), it can in some instances span multiple lines in the mobile version, breaking the "tag" illusion:

[image: Example of the issue, showing the "mac-os-x" tag spanning multiple lines]

The fix already exists in the desktop version. Simply set:

```
.post-tag {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build. Thanks for providing the solution!